# ANy Book for Cpanel/whm API programming

Tags: untagged

HI guys ,

I was thinking of building a custom script for billing managemenet in WHM.

Is there any Book Published on that or any place where i can learn it.

There site does have any practical example of doing that

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried searching?  A quick Google search for "cPanel API" returned the cPanel documentation on the subject as the first link (http://twiki.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/AutomationIntegration/XmlApi).

Comment: Actually i was looking for some Book with the printed documentation